# ¿Como programar tareas en Java EE 7

Tags: spring, java-ee

Tengo una app web realizada en Java EE 7, quiero saber como puedo incluir tareas programadas en el mismo, he revisado Scheduling Tasks pero lo que aún no entiendo es sobre donde configuro aquello, en que archivo de configuración debo hacerlo y como lo ejecuto, por ejemplo quiero ejecutar una tarea cada 24 horas, donde lo programo, como lo ejecuto.

Espero me puedan ayudar con eso, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Usas spring? o jee puro?

Comment: Estoy usando spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En EJB, con Scheduling, creas un método con la anotación asignando el tiempo, y ella se ejecuta, pero tienes que poder levantar el EJB en un servidor de aplicaciones, aprendiendo eso, lo demás es fácil